# Django: Foreign key from parent to child table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I want to have a foreign key link from Parent table to child table ; for a site which is mainly backend powered. Currently only admin part of site is active as that is the only part required to get our information team working.

App structure:

attraction:

|
  |--- model
  |    |
  |    | --- _ _init__.py
  |    | --- imagemetadata.py
  |
  | --- models.py
  | --- admin.py

(imagemetadata is under directory model)

file imagemetadata.py

```
from attraction.models import Attraction

class ImageMetadata(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank=True, null=True)
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    attraction = models.ForeignKey(Attraction)
```

file models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Attraction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

file admin.py

```
class ImageMetadataInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ImageMetadata
    extra = 2

class AttractionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['name', 'description', 'url']}),
    ]

    inlines = [ImageMetadataInline, PriceInline]

admin.site.register(Attraction, AttractionAdmin)
```

The problem i am facing is i cant get a foreign key from Attraction to Imagemetadata. If I try to make a two way foreign key import error occurs. ( Cyclic imports not allowed in Python).
And because of the structure of admin , there cant be a foreign key just from Attraction to ImageMetadata, as Django doesnt allow that.

Is there a way to make the foreign key point from Attraction to ImageMetadata, without changing the structure of admin ?

Comment: Is there any strong reason why do you want to separate your models in different files? All models should be by convention in the models.py, unless you can really justify the ground for this and you know exactly what you do.

Comment: @cezar I want to separate them into files as i want my code to be as granular as possible. By convention, it is good practice to maintian readability in a scalable code. I expect to have more than 30 Models. Maintaining and connecting them in a way i want i hard to maintain in the same file. Plus (acc to industry or even personal standards) convention dictates that you shouldnt have more than 200 lines in one file, or even more than 1 class in one class.

Comment: You have to define ``class Meta`` in your ImageData and put ``app_label`` there. The value should be the name of your app.

Comment: Could you tell me how to define Meta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the class Meta as following:

```
class ImageMetadata(models.Model):
    # ... your fields

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'attraction'
```

Make a sub-directory `models` in your app directory. Split your models into different files. Then edit the `__init__.py`:

```
from model_file1 import *
from model_fiel2 import *
# and so on
```

Now you can make:

```
from attraction.models import whatever
```

I split in this way my tests. It should work for the models too.

However I would suggest you first to rethink your design. In Python is absolutely all right to have many classes in one file. Python is neither PHP nor Java. 200 LOC per file is nothing. I would say it is absolutely okay if your models.py are up to 2k LOC. Just my personal opinion. Maybe some Python gurus here can correct me.

Before you split your models.py consider if you can maybe split your project in smaller apps. Maybe ImageMetadata should belong to another app. You can't achieve granularity by splitting the models.py into many files. Just because you have many smaller files instead of one big file doesn't mean the project logic is split. You should break down your logic into few self-containing apps.

Comment: Here I found a link that explains the above a little bit further: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookSplitModelsToFiles

Comment: nice explanation, cezar!